# Mega menu using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to do something like this using react.js Material UI. I know we can use the menu component in Material UI But how can we have multiple columns and rows as shown in the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you use a pop-up dialog instead of a menu.

But to use it with a menu you could just create the view separately and pass it to the menu as a child.

Like.

custom_menu.js <- menu view code in this file

```
const CustomMenu = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            {/* menu code here */}
        </div>
}

export default CustomMenu;
```

import this js file to the js file which will have the definition of the menu.

x.js <- custom_menu.js used in this file

```
import CustomMenu from "..." // path/to/custom_menu.js

const X = () => {
    return (
        <MenuItem>
            <CustomMenu />
        </MenuItem>
    )
}

export default X;
```

Answer (score 1):

Material-Ui [allows you to target](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/) the `<ul>` generated by the `<Menu>` component via class `MuiList-root`. All we need to do is set it to `display: flex` and set the `flex-direction` to `row`.

Then all `MenuItems` we set inside divs will be their own columns.

```
<Menu
  id="my-menu"
  anchorEl={myAnchor}
  open={Open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  sx={{
    "& .MuiList-root": {  // Target the <ul>
     display: "flex",
     flexDirection: "row",
     },
   }}
>
     // Column One
     <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
          <MenuItem>Item #1</MenuItem>
     </div>

     // Column Two
     <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
         <MenuItem>Item #2</MenuItem>
     </div>
 </Menu>
```